# Reading URL's from google docs spreadsheet python

Tags: python, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to read a list of URL's that I have on google docs. What I want to do is read the URL's in from google doc spreadsheet then scrape each URL.

```
import gdata.docs.data
import gdata.docs.client
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import re, os

username        = 'myemail.nuigalway@gmail.com'
password         = 'mypassword'
doc_name        = 'My document'

gd_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
gd_client.email = username 
gd_client.password = password  
gd_client.source = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc? key=0AkGb10ekJtfQdG9EOHN0VzRDdVhWaG1kNVEtdVpyRlE#gid=0'
gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

q = gdata.spreadsheet.service.DocumentQuery()
q['title'] = doc_name
q['title-exact'] = 'true'
feed = gd_client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed(query=q)
spreadsheet_id = feed.entry[0].id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1]
feed = gd_client.GetWorksheetsFeed(spreadsheet_id)
worksheet_id = feed.entry[0].id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1]

rows = gd_client.GetListFeed(spreadsheet_id, worksheet_id).entry


for row in rows:
    for key in row.custom:
        urls = row.custom[key].text 
    newlist = urls
print 'this is a list',  newlist 

elec_urls = newlist.strip()

#After this each the Url in the list is scraped using scraperwiki
```

This works fine if I only have one URL in the spredsheet, I don't, when I have more that one URL in the document the program only scrapes the last Url.

I thought using a loop would solve this something to cycle from newlist[0] to newlist[i] but found out that newlist[0] is = to h of the h t t p://(URL) Last entered urls and newlist[1]= t and so on.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, `newlist` is the last URL, so naturally when you ask for its indices you get individual letters. You need to create a list before the loop and then append each url to it, instead of setting `urls` to the text of each one:

```
urls = []
for row in rows:
    for key in row.custom:
        urls.append(row.custom[key].text)
```

Now `urls` is a list where each element is one URL.

Comment: Ah should have seen that... My brains not working today thanks man